# Полупрозрачный фон для текста

Tags: css

Как сделать полупрозрачный фон для текста, так чтоб просвечивал фон страницы?

Не получается сделать полупрозрачный фон для текста, а так же беда с расположением элементов на странице, - к примеру, как картинку-ссылку поместить в одну линию с  текстом-ссылкой?

Comment: фон - картинка?

Comment: фон сайта - картинка, фон текста нет, просто полупрозрачная заливка через которую видно картинку=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это css. Прозрачный фон делаете так:

```
.class{
    background:url(fon.jpg); 
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

А чтобы элемент на элемент накладывать, воспользуйтесь `position:absolute;` - это тоже css. Удачи.

Comment: плюсанука я  этот вариант )

Comment: не за что, хоть чем то я могу помочь)))

Answer (score 0):

1. если текст находится в div и надо на него еще один фон положить, ставил бы бэкграунд с прозрачным фоном подготовленным в ФШ
2. если просто надо раскрасить буквы - это просто =)
   Отдельного свойства прозрачности элемента в css не помню =)